# NonlinearModelFit and FindFit not Working

Tags: fitting, nonlinear

I have a function, not very complicated, somewhat similar to an infinite, converging Geometric Progression. Here is my function: Y = n^t / t!. Nonlinear Model Fit works not at all with this expression. Find Fit works but the fit to my data is pretty much worthless. I have tried using Method->"Automatic", "QuasiNewton", and "NMinimize". Advice? Suggestions?

```
NonlinearModelFit[data1,(a n^x) / (m x!)[x, a, n, m], {{a,3},{n,5},{m,2}},x, Method->"Automatic"]
```

Comment: Please, post your actual Mathematica code.

Comment: I added OP's code from an OP comment to my first answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My code, nowhere near as sophisticated as your code: NonlinearModelFit[data1,(a n^x) / (m x!)[x, a, n, m], {{a,3},{n,5},{m,2}},x, Method->"Automatic"]

In Mathematica you cannot define a function and invoke it in this way:

```
(a n^x) / (m x!)[x, a, n, m]
```

You have to define a function:

```
Y[x_, a_, n_, m_] := (a n^x) / (m x!);
Y[x, a, n, m]
```

or use a pure function, like this:

```
(#1 #3^#1)/(#4 #1!) &[x, a, n, m]
```

or like this:

```
Function[{x, a, n, m}, (a n^x)/(m x!)][x, a, n, m]
```

Here is complete code using your (not working) `NonlinearModelFit` code:

```
SeedRandom[232];
Block[{c = 20, n = 6},
  data1 = 
   Table[{t, (n + RandomReal[{-0.01, 0.01}]*n)^t/t!}, {t, 0, c, 0.2}]
  ];

ListPlot[data1]

Clear[Y];
Y[x_, a_, n_, m_] := (a n^x) / (m x!);

nlm = NonlinearModelFit[data1, 
  Y[x, a, n, m], {{a, 3}, {n, 5}, {m, 2}}, x, Method -> "Automatic"]

Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 20}, Epilog :> Point[data1], 
 PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

### First answer

Is this something you are looking for:

```
nlm =
 Module[{c = 20, n = 3, k = 12, a, as, tbl, nlm},
  as = Array[a, k];
  tbl = Table[{t, n^t/t!}, {t, 0, c, 0.2}];
  nlm = NonlinearModelFit[tbl, Table[t^i, {i, k}].as, as, t];
  Echo@Plot[nlm[x], {x, 0, 10}, Epilog :> Point[tbl], PlotStyle -> {Orange, Thick}, PlotRange -> All];
  nlm
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: My code, nowhere near as sophisticated as your code:
NonlinearModelFit[data1,(a n^x) / (m x!)[x, a, n, m], {{a,3},{n,5},{m,2}},x, Method->"Automatic"]